# Sunspot Solr not starting with "You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server"

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, solr, ruby-on-rails-4

Before redeploy my application and restart my server, Sunsport Solr stopped and can`t be started anymore, although it was working before the redeploy + restart. When I run

```
rake sunspot:solr:run RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

I receive the following

```
** Invoke sunspot:solr:start (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Execute sunspot:solr:start
rake aborted!
You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
```

But java -version return the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.4.el6_5-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Don`t know what to do anymore, already tried to remove solr folder from the app and run the install again (rails g sunspot_solr:install) , but no lucky...

I`m on Ruby 2.0.0  Rails 4.0.0.rc1 and the last version of sunspot solt

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have a valid Java Runtime (e.g. /usr/bin/java) **and also have a valid JDK installed**.

When you run `which java`, if you don't have a valid JDK installed, you will get an error to that effect.

You will not be able to run the Solr server if you don't have both installed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. When running the following command.

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start -t

** Invoke sunspot:solr:start (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:solr:start
rake aborted!
Sunspot::Solr::Server::JavaMissing: You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
```

By using this command

```
$ bundle exec rake --execute 'puts which java'
```

I am getting '/usr/bin/java'.

But by the following command

```
$ java --version -> 'No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

I am using Mac OSX and it prompted a message and clicking on more info it goes to:

```
oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

So I installed JDK 8 from the link:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
```

for mac OSX

```
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-macosx-x64.dmg

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

After that Solr server run successfully :) .

**In your case you have to reinstall the JDK from the above link to make it work**

You have openJDK runtime environment. Switch to Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, to make Solr work. Read this ([difference-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360011/technically-what-is-the-main-difference-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk#comment27153592_17364418))

Run the Solr server background by

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start -t

Successfully started Solr ...
```

Stop Solr server:

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop -t
```

Start solr server in the foreground:

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run -t
```

Answer (score 0):

'rake' unable to find the java.
Make sure java executable is in your path that the rake task can see.

Comment: Could you please give me some more directions on this ? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you execute java and rake command in the same shell
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Well everything seems to be ok, at least with java, how can I check where rake is looking for the path ?

Comment: run on your console: ``bundle exec rake --execute 'puts `which java`'`` or ``bundle exec rake --execute 'puts `env`'``

Comment: Thanks wacko! I`m getting /usr/bin/java with your command, and the same path without the rake command....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you did to fix things here. When I run the aforementioned command I get `/usr/bin/java`. When I run `java -version` I get `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3)` which means Java is installed. I don't understand why Solr isn't starting up as it should...did you combine the two commands or something (echo java path + start solr)?