# What is the difference of the anonymous internal class directly call the external class instance method in the OpenJDK and Oracle?

Tags: javac, java

Today, I reviewed same Android code, and found a strange phenomenon.

It is the anonymous internal class directly called the external class instance method.

In my mind, directly calling a method is equivalent to adding `this` directly before the method, and `this` is an instance of an inner class.

According to this logic, an instance of an external class is invoked directly in the anonymous inner class, that will caused the compile ERROR.

But actually compile this application, and no problem. And the running log is normal.

Therefore, writing a simple Demo to verify the previous concept is wrong. code show as below:

```
public class InnerClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InnerClass().process();
    }

    public void process() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(toString("test"));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public String toString(String string) {
        return string;
    }
}
```

In the Oracle:
[image]

In the OpenJDK:
[image]

So, What is the difference of the anonymous internal class directly call the external class instance method in the OpenJDK and Oracle?

Where can I find documentation to see these differences?

I worked hard, but did not get a clear answer.

Thanks.

P.S.

In According to my point of view

```
public class InnerClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InnerClass().process();
    }

    public void process() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // In According to my point of view
                // toString("test")
                // <==>
                // this.toString("test")
                // and `this` is the instance of Thread
                // what's the error of my view?
                System.out.println(toString("test"));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public String toString(String string) {
        return string;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360011/technically-what-is-the-main-difference-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk

Comment: Also note that one is Java 8, the other java 7.

Comment: @MacStevins I see the url.， But I cannot find the detail. For example the difference of that javac handle anonymous inner class directly call an instance method of an outer class

Comment: Why are you comparing Windows and Unix? And Java 7 to Java 8? Limit the external differences before you say there is a difference in the software itself.

Comment: There is no such difference between OpenJDK and Oracle javac (and there won’t be any in the future). You are just comparing Java 7 to Java 8 (on different OS and locales).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(toString("test"));
        }
```

is calling `toString` on the anonymous `Thread` subclass, and that is `Thread::toString()`.  There is no `Thread::toString(String)`, and the `toString(String)` method from the enclosing scope is not considered.

The JLS states that it will only check an enclosing / outer class for a method if there is no method with the required name in the inner class.  See [JLS 15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1):

> If the form is MethodName, that is, just an Identifier, then:
>
> - If the Identifier appears in the scope of a visible method declaration
>     with that name (§6.3, §6.4.1), then:
>
>   - If there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member, let T be the innermost such type declaration. The class or
>       interface to search is T.
>
>     This search policy is called the "comb rule". It effectively looks for methods in a nested class's superclass hierarchy before looking
>       for methods in an enclosing class and its superclass hierarchy. See
>       §6.5.7.1 for an example.

As to why OpenJDK Java 7 accepts your test class .... if that is actually true, I'd call that a compiler bug.  But it would be a general Java 7 bug not an OpenJDK specific one.  The `javac` codebases are (AFAIK) identical for Oracle and OpenJDK releases of the same version.

Interestingly, I have a copy of Oracle Java 6, and `javac` from that version also calls this a compilation error as well.

```
$ /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac InnerClass.java 
InnerClass.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol: method toString(java.lang.String)
                System.out.println(toString("test"));
                                   ^
1 error
```

So ... maybe ... you should rerun your OpenJDK Java 7 test, and make sure you are compiling the same source code!

Comment: `toString(String)` is not `toString()`. And it is in both cases `Thread#toString`

Comment: I know that .........

Comment: hm, why do you say it calls Object.toString() then?

Comment: Because it is **just** the name that matters in this case.  See the JLS text I have just quoted.  Indeed, read the whole context.

Comment: Rule #1 - If the java compiler says some code is incorrect, then *believe* the java compiler ... unless the JLS clearly contradicts it.  In this case, there are 3 versions of javac saying this is incorrect.  (I have also tested OpenJDK Java 8.)

Comment: Well, yes the code is clearly incorrect, it’s interesting to know why it compiles ,)

Comment: Well, I'm not convinced that it does.  But I can't easily get hold of the OpenJDK compiler that the OP is using ... to check for myself.

Comment: BTW i would change `Runnable` into anonymous `Thread` subtype, or do you think it’s related to the run() declaration? — I think in that case it’s more the lexical scope, right?

Comment: I see `new Thread() { }` in the original question. So talking about Runnable seems confusing.

Comment: Ah .... I see what you mean.

Comment: BTW (The more often I read that JLS part the less I understand what it means :)

Comment: Rule #2 - if you don't understand what the JLS means, it *probably* means what the java compiler says it means :-)

Comment: 6.5.7.1 does describe it a bit simpler to understand, (still surprising never encountered that before). It is a bit unexpected when you are not familiar with method names as identifiers. Wonder if that really helps in cases.

Comment: I can make sure you are compiling the same source code!

Comment: I can assure you that >>I<< am compiling the same source code with OpenJDK Java 6 and Java 8.  Anyhow, it is not really relevant.  If you are getting a compiler to accept that code, then that compiler has a bug in it.  Fix your code, move on.